# Using HtmlAgillityPack how can get data and attributes HTML tags?

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

In this Html code I need to get attributes and data from html tags. This is an example:

...

```
   <tr class="first-row"><td class="first-cell tl"><a href="../matchdetails.php?matchid=MaxATAKK" onclick="win(this.href, 560, 500, 0, 1); return false;">Gefle - Kalmar</a></td><td class="result"><a href="../matchdetails.php?matchid=MaxATAKK" onclick="win(this.href, 560, 500, 0, 1); return false;">4:2</a></td><td class="odds best-betrate" data-odd="3.53"></td><td class="odds" data-odd="3.37"></td><td class="odds" data-odd="2.04"></td><td class="last-cell nobr date">18.07.2016</td></tr>
```

...

So, I need to get data between td tags and attributes (data-odd).

This is my C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace bexscraping
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string url = "http://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/sweden/allsvenskan/results/";
            HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(url);
            foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table"))
            {

                //node.Remove();

                outputLabel.Text += node.InnerText;
            }



        }

    }

}
```

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Try filtering using Xpath: .SelectNodes("//td[@class=""odds""]") This, as XPath Doc says, select all nodes td that contain an attribute "class" equals to "odds".

Comment: Thanks, do you have some link or can you give me an example? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is some Msdn Examples: [XPath Examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx); [XPath Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256115(v=vs.110).aspx)

According to your snippet you could select all tags **TD** that contain attribute **data-odd**.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        string url = "http://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/sweden/allsvenskan/results/";
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(url);
        var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@data-odd]");
        foreach (HtmlNode node in nodes)
        {
            //Here process your node
            //Example: to get data-odd value
            var val = node.GetAttributeValue("data-odd", "");
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your anser. I tried it but I got just one error message: "The name odds does not exist in the current context". What's wrong? Thanks again

Comment: @Marci Sorry, i tested the code, but i copied badly. I Update the answer. Just not Odds(0), but node.

Comment: I tried your correction but I got another error, more or less is this: HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlAttributeCollection ' does not contain a definition of ' Item ' and has not been found no extension method ' Item ' accepting a first argument of type ' HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlAttributeCollection ' . Probably missing a using directive or a reference to an assembly.

Comment: Maybe I need to insert another using?

Comment: @Marci I sorry, it's my bad, because i tested my code in vb.net and then i translated it in c#, but some methods are different. I edit again my answer.

Comment: Ok, and now I can show the results? :) I tried in foreach to put it but I see just a value,                 outputLabel.Text = val.ToString();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117827/discussion-between-cicciorocca-and-marci).